# adding data to an existing empty dataframe containing only column names

Tags: python, pandas

How can I add data to an existing empty column in a dataframe?

I have an empty dataframe with column names (stock tickers)

[image]

I am trying to add data to each stock, basically, populate the dataframe column by column, from left to right based on the header name.

I am pulling the data from another CSV file which looks like this (CSV file name = column name in the dataframe Im trying to populate):

[image]

PS aditional issue may arise due to the length of data available for each stock, eg. I may have a list of 10 values for the first stock, 0 for the second, and 25 for third. I plan to save this in a CSV, so perhaps it could not cause too big of an issue.

[image]

I have tried the following idea but without luck. any suggestions are welcome.

```
import pandas as pd
import os


path = 'F:/pathToFiles'

Russell3k_Divs = 'Russel3000-Divs/'
Russell3k_Tickers =  'Russell-3000-Stock-Tickers-List.csv'

df_tickers =  pd.read_csv(path + Russell3k_Tickers)

divFls = os.listdir(path + Russell3k_Divs)

for i in divFls:
    df = pd.read_csv(path + Russell3k_Divs + i)
    Div = df['Dividends']
    i = i[0].split('.')

    df_tickers[i] = df_tickers.append(Div)
    print(df_tickers)
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
from tqdm import tqdm


path = 'F:/pathToFiles'

Russell3k_Divs = 'Russel3000-Divs/'
Russell3k_Tickers =  'Russell-3000-Stock-Tickers-List.csv'

df_tickers = pd.DataFrame()

divFls = os.listdir(path + Russell3k_Divs)

for i in tqdm(divFls):
    df = pd.read_csv(path + Russell3k_Divs + i)

    i = i.split('.')[0]

    df[str(i)] = df['Date']

    df_tickers = df_tickers.join(df[str(i)], how='outer')


df_tickers.to_csv('Russell-3000-Stock-Tickers-List1.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58364165/2) to the question [adding data to an existing empty dataframe containing only column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58364165/adding-data-to-an-existing-empty-dataframe-containing-only-column-names) by the OP [Mr.Riply](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5183031/mr-riply) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>